# How do you seed relationships for Mongoid in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to create a small game server using Ruby on Rails, Mongo, with Mongoid as the ORM, with Devise for authentication. I'm trying to modify the db/seeds.rb to seed several users and game documents.

How do you create a seed between two Mongo/Mongoid relationships?

I have **Users** and **Games**. Users **have_many** Games. I've found examples of creating a seed database for "embeds_many" and "embedded_in", but not for has / belongs. A follow-up would be if this is the proper architecture (there's a third model "Turns" that will be embedded in the "Game".

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  embeds_many :turns

  field :title, type: String
  field :user_id, type: Integer
  field :current_player, type: Integer
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :games


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
  field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :default => ""

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :encrypted_password

  field :name                 
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :email, :case_sensitive => false
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  ...
  ... bunch of fields to support devise gem
```

end

I've tried two ways to make this work and neither create a relationship in the database:

```
puts 'EMPTY THE MONGODB DATABASE'
::Mongoid::Sessions.default.drop

puts 'SETTING UP DEFAULT USER LOGIN'
user = User.create! :name => 'First User', :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'please', :password_confirmation => 'please'
puts 'New user created: ' << user.name

game = Game.create! :title => 'First Game', :user_id => user._id, :current_player => user._id
puts 'New game created: ' << game.title
user.games.push(game)
user.save

game2 = Game.create(:title => 'Foo Game', users: [
  User.create(:name => 'd1', :email => 'd1@example.com', :password => 'd', :password_confirmation => 'd'),
  User.create(:name => 'd2', :email => 'd2@example.com', :password => 'd', :password_confirmation => 'd'),
  User.create(:name => 'd3', :email => 'd3@example.com', :password => 'd', :password_confirmation => 'd')
  ])
puts 'Second game created: ' << game2.title
```

Comment: don't you have field definitions on your models?

Comment: Sure, I've updated it to include the entire "Game" and "User" model. Though the "User" model has more supporting fields for devise gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are manually trying to create the relationship.
Remove `field :user_id, type: Integer` from the Game model
And try
`user.games.create!(title: "First Game")`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code instead of  `belongs_to :games` in Game class:
`embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :game`
And replace `has_many :games` of User class by 
`embeds_many :games`

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I wasn't sure if I should change the nature of my objects to adhere to the seed code I had, but I felt that a "has_many" relationship made more sense in terms of thinking of "Users" and "Games"